# Is there any sense to useContext in React?

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt

Hello i need help with my app.
What sense is to put my User data to useContext if when i refresh page all data disapear?
How to make this context permament?
I have been sitting with this all day, and when i try to get data in HomePage, everything is ok until i refresh page.

The second question is about JWT. It's used only on server side, right? It's verifing the token when I'm making server reqest only?

below is my code

> App.js

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import AddNewAnnoucement from "./components/pages/AddNewAnnoucement/AddNewAnnoucement";
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Annoucements from "./components/pages/Annoucements/Annoucements";
import Register from "./components/pages/Register/Register";
import Login from "./components/pages/Login/Login";
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { getProfile, tokenIsValid } from './service/userService.js'

export const UserContext = createContext();
function App() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
        token: undefined,
        user: undefined,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const isLoggedIn = async () => {
            let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
            if (token == null) {
                localStorage.setItem("token", "")
                token = ""
            }

            const tokenResponse = tokenIsValid(token);
            tokenResponse.then((res) => {
                if (res.data) {
                    const userResponse = getProfile(token);
                    userResponse.then((res) => {
                        setUserData({
                            token: token,
                            data: res.data
                        })
                    })
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
            )
        }
        isLoggedIn();
    }, [])

    return <>
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='container'>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path='/annoucements' element={<Annoucements />} />
                    <Route path='/annoucements/add' element={<AddNewAnnoucement />} />
                    <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Context is primarily used **when some data needs to be accessible by many components at different nesting levels**.

Comment: So i need my user data to be accessible, but it's useless when i refresh the page and then it disapears

Comment: Context is just about having a data store which can be accessed throughout your app. If you want it to persist when refreshing the page you'll have to add that functionality yourself. Firstly, you should separate your context and its logic into its own file, just like you do with a redux reducer, rather than blend it with your App component and use local set state functions as context values. Then, when loading initial context values or setting them, you can get/set to the browser's `localStorage`. That way it's persisted after page refreshing